# When do I run Honeywell ER150C whole home fresh air system?

Tags: hvac

My home was built in 2002 (south Texas) with A Honeywell ER150C fresh air system. About three years ago I replaced my two thermostats with Nests. The downstairs thermostat was a 4 wire Honeywell thermostat that interfaced with a Honeywell 8900 perfect climate module. I disconnected the 8900 module and connected the Nest right to the HVAC unit. Basically, I lost the functionality of the ER150C unit. Recently I had a notion to try to use the ER150C to introduce more fresh air and remove mustiness. I plugged it in and connected the two control wires and it started right up at full speed. The jury is still out on how much it helps but we will see. My questions:

1. When should I run the ER150C for optimal performance? Since I can't use the 8900/thermostat combo anymore, I put a z-wave plus switch on the ER150C. Should I make it go on only when the AC/heat is running or when the fan is running or all the time or something else?
2. would I be better off with a different thermostat that could control the ER150C directly?
3. Is it worth bothering using the ER150C at all?

The manual says:
HOW MUCH VENTILATION DO I NEED?

> During the seasons that your windows and doors are closed (winter and summer if you have air conditioning), the ventilator should operate continuously when the home is occupied, and either continuously or intermittently when not occupied.
> For most installations, the ventilator will normally be set to operate continuously on low speed with the option of going to high speed as the need arises. For example, if you are entertaining and there is a large number of people present (some may be smoking), the ventilator should be switched to high speed.

Comment: Have you looked at dedicated fresh-air controls such as the FanCycler?

Comment: Couldn't find much info on FanCycler does it interface with thermostat? How does it know when to run ventilation?

Comment: It's a timer-based system, but I got the name wrong, sorry -- it's AirCycler, not FanCycler

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't believe what the manual says?

Comment: I just wasn't sure whether they meant to have the ventilation run in tandem with the AC/heat or run continuously on its own no matter whether the heat/AC was on or not. On second look they probably mean with or without the AC. Also, the unit was wired into the 8900 climate control module + special thermostat so it was controlled automatically in a way that I don't fully understand. I can now control the units on/off through my Smartthings smart home hub based on the thermostat readings, states, people home or not, windows opened or closed, etc. I cannot however, control the speed.

Comment: The wiring diagram is at [link](http://www.ntsupply.com/files/products/HWER150Install.pdf) on page 10 - not sure how to control the speed automatically.

Comment: From your quoted text `the ventilator should operate continuously when the home is occupied, and either continuously or intermittently when not occupied.` Sounds to me like they suggest running it at _all_ times when SmartThings says you're home, then, most reasonably, when the rest of the HVAC system runs when you're not home. However, since you've been living there for a while without it running at all, it seems that turning it on _when you want_ would be an improvement of sorts.

Comment: Thanks for helping me think through this. Bottom line is I don't know how much electricity takes but I might just let it run all the time, I don't see any downside to doing so. As I go through the different seasons I'll see how it works and adjust as necessary. We may be able to keep the thermostat higher now without mustiness.

Comment: I have the same unit just one model up an have it running constantly. Make sure you balance the unit and you should be good to go

Comment: So just a closing comment for whoever may look at this question. After much discussion and rereading, I have this unit hooked into my Samsung Smarthings hub via zwave plug. I set it up to run using webcore using the following conditions:  1) Nest thermostat is in any mode except Off 2) Outside dew point is less than 70. This seems to work well and keep the inside humidity at a good level so far.